# From one color to another with percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website I have a variable ,let's call it x, that it is a percentage, what I need is a way to define that 0% is red and 100% is blue, so if I get a 50% from x them the color should be the combination of this two color, if I get 70% should be a combination where the red intesity is bigger, and so on with any percentage x gives me.

Comment: Show effort. What's your code so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red color has hexa code is: ff0000 (decimal code is: 16711680), Blue has 0000ff (decimal code is 255). You can use parseInt(hexcode, 16) to convert from hex to dec. Your algorithm is: max value 16711680 is 100%; min value 255 is 0%. Then the x% will be 255+(16711680-255)*x/100. And you need to convert this value to hex by using toString(16).
Here example:

```js
$('#control').change(function(e){
  var vl = $(this).val();
  var min = 255; //blue color -> 0000ff
  var max = 16711680; //red color -> ff0000
  var current = 255+Math.round(vl*(max-min)/100);
  var hex = current.toString(16);
  var currentHex = '#'+'0'.repeat(6-hex.length)+hex;
  $('#colorcode').html(currentHex);
  $('#box').css('backgroundColor', currentHex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='range' value='0' min='0' max='100' id='control' style='width:200px;'>
<div id='colorcode'>Color code</div>
<div style='width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#0000ff;' id='box'></div>
```